ATT internet service incompatible with Macbook email
My elderly neighbor is having trouble with email on a new macBook.
Internet service is from AT&T in California.
ATT apparently farmed out personal email service to Yahoo.
So when you receive or send email from your ATT account, behind the scenes you are secretly logged into Yahoo.  You can also go to yahoo.com directly and read/write email, but you probably don't have any mail folders there (you created them all on your local system).
AT&T recently put in a new security service, involving OAuth, or alternatively creating a 16-char "secure email key".   They explain how to create this string here: https://www.att.com/support/article/email-support/KM1240308/
That page says you are supposed to replace your current email password with the secure key.  (By "email password" I mean the password that you use when you login to your ATT email account at Yahoo.  This was being provided automagically when you used the Apple mail.app to get email). Standard Apple macBook email seems to be incompatible with this new "secure email key".
The Apple macBook email app, when you hit "send", comes back with an error window saying the password (the 16-char string) is not correct.  I've created and tested 4 different "secure email keys" - none of them are accepted instead of the password.
ATT also offers the offhand advice "For an IMAP account, delete the existing password for both the IMAP and SMTP servers. Replace them with your secure mail key."
Is that "instead of replacing your att.net account password?" or "as well as replacing your att.net password?"
Can anyone inform me how to navigate to a place on MacOS that lets me enter new passwords for IMAP and SMTP mail servers.  Neighbor is running MacOS 14.4.something
This incompatible ATT software has rendered my neighbor's email useless for the last 2 days, and email is her main contact with the outside world.  I have been thru 4 levels of grossly inadequate ATT "support".  First the chat line, then the hour long wait for ATT customer service person, then the outside support company (rtm-att.directly.com), then when they failed, they referred me to a secret ATT support chat URL, supposedly "experts" but which was no help at all.
PLEASE help me fix this problem for an elderly shut-in neighbor.

This article may help you with this problem. •• If your friend's Mac does not have a Time Machine backup, purchase an external HDD/SSD and set it up  ASAP. My 93yo mother's entire digital life has been saved twice by restores from regular backups (she knows to check to see the last backup.)

Well, I appreciate the recommendation to keep file back-ups through time machine.  It has no connection to the ATT email problem I am trying to solve though.

I agree it has nothing to do with the original email problem. Just a hint when working with agéd clients for you, and their, peace of mind. Does the link I provided give you any leads on the problem? Apple Mail.app email account passwords are usually saved in Keychain Access. Open the app, and in the sidebar, select the Default keychain "login", then click In the search field in the upper right and search for the email address you need to find. A smaller pop-up will have a checkbox to show the password. You'll need the user login password to view.
